# Unable to get Changes Using uSNChanged

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I want to get incremental changes from Active Directory using C#. And for that I am trying to build a solution as mentioned in the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/polling-for-changes-using-usnchanged

However, I am facing following problems:

1. There is no uSNChanged property available for user (although it is available for OU i.e. OrganizationalUnit). I can see only following properties for user.

[image]

2. When I am moving users from OU1 to OU2, then `highestcommittedusn` get incremented but when I am querying for changes (`search.Filter = "(uSNChanged>=13000)"`) using following code, I **DO NOT** get any updates.
3. same case is for adding a user inside an OU.

Sample Code is mentioned below:

```cs
public static void GetUpdates()
{
    var myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
    var search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
    search.Filter = "(uSNChanged>=13000)";
    search.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
    var results = search.FindAll();
    Console.WriteLine(results.Count);
}

public static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://adfs.fed.abcd.com/DC=adfs,DC=fed,DC=abcd,DC=com");
    ldapConnection.Path = "adfs.fed.abcd.com";
    ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
            return ldapConnection;
}

 private static long GetHighestUsn()
 {
     using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldapPath))
     {
          var filter = "(&(objectClass=*))";
          var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(null, filter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Base, "highestCommittedUSN");
          var response = connection.SendRequest(searchRequest) as SearchResponse;
          var usn = response.Entries[0].Attributes["highestcommittedusn"][0];
          return Convert.ToInt64(usn);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

### **Edit:**

1. I have only ONE domain controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: The code was correct.

I needed to provide "Read all user information" permission to the user (which was making the request) and after that I starting getting usnchanged property with every object including user.

Steps to enable permission is given in below article.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b34f7295-4989-4440-93af-cebd6d66c711/cannot-read-the-usnchanged-attribute-for-some-users-why?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Ha, I wonder if this was not that but because it was a local instance I skipped this part thinking the user you used was high privileged at least to perform testing :) Nice you found.

Comment: Actually, I was using Admin user only but still I needed to do that explicitly, not sure why.. but glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For `GetHighestUsn` I think the `null` from `new SearchRequest(null ...`  should be replaced by an empty string to get RootDSE.

Secondly you mix `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`: you should better stick to one. It is not clear what is the value for `ldapPath` in `new LdapConnection(ldapPath))`. If it is "adfs.fed.abcd.com" and you have more than one domain controller, you cannot know exactly which one will answer, this is related to last remark.

Last, `USNChanged` attribute is a non-replicated attribute, meaning that you should always request the same domain controller to get updates. Another domain controller will store a complete different value for the same object.

Normally every object should return `USNChanged` attribute unless you have specified a finite list of attributes to return in which case you must include it as well.

EDIT: Include sample code (Powershell)

- System.DirectoryServices

```
    $entry = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]::new("LDAP://localhost:50005/O=MyAppInstance")
    $entry.psbase.AuthenticationType = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Secure
    $searcher = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]::new($entry)
    $searcher.Filter = "(uSNChanged>=13004)"
    $searcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Subtree
    $results = $searcher.FindAll()
    $results.Count
```

- System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

```
    $con = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection]::new("localhost:50005")
    $con.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Negotiate
    $con.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
    $con.Bind()

    $req = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest]::new()
    $req.DistinguishedName = "O=MyAppInstance"
    $req.Scope = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope]::Subtree
    $req.Filter = "(uSNChanged>=13004)"

    $res = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchResponse]$con.SendRequest($req)
    $res.Entries.Count
```

Comment: Thanks @Hazrelle for your quick response on this.

I am getting same value for HighestUsn if I am passing null or empty string. and its value is getting updated after every operation (e.g. moving a user from one OU to another). So, its not a concern.

Yes, ldap path is "adfs.fed.abcd.com".

I have only ONE domain controller and its a local environment. So, i will connect to always same domain controller.

Any idea why it is not showing USNChanged attribute for user and subsequently, moving/adding not captured in search result?

Comment: Normally this should work as expected.
A new user is being assigned:

- uSNChanged: 13005 
- uSNCreated: 13005

A user moved is being assigned:

- uSNChanged: 13006; 
- uSNCreated: 5000;

I've performed a quick check on a local ADLDS instance and this is the results I have.

Comment: And I've tested both librairies and I get the matching results (add and move) from the latest known value for "highestcommittedusn" (i.e 13004) on the Domain Controller. The new "highestcommittedusn" is 13006.

Comment: Can you please share your code ? Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: I am too getting updated "highestcommittedusn" value.. its just that I am not getting updated result via search in C#